# Set form to submitted once it's loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I am trying to submit the form initially but when I try to do `vm.form.$setSubmitted();`, vm.form is still undefined at that point as it takes a while to load. How can I submit the form once it stops being undefined?

I have written this sort of `$watcher` but doesn't work.

```
$scope.$watch(vm.form, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue !== oldValue) {
        vm.form.$setSubmitted();
    }
});
```

Or maybe there's a more appropriate way I'm unaware of.

Comment: Call a function once the form is loaded, or use synchronous code and put the `vm.form.$setSubmitted();` below the code that generates the form...

Comment: Could you not simply add a `&& newValue !== undefined` onto your `if`? You'll also likely want to remove the watcher once you have successfully called `$setSubmitted()` just to reduce what Angular is watching unnecessarily.

Comment: Please include the HTML code.